# Display data from Firebase database (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is an example of how my Firebase database looks

[image: database]

What I am trying to do is access what's inside pic1, pic2, etc. But I'm getting an error and it's not showing any data at all.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
 private void getData(){
        firebaseDatabaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        // get reference to 'users' node
        booksInstance = firebaseDatabaseInstance.getReference("mainAlbum");

        booksInstance.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                setData(dataSnapshot);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });

    }

    List<List<String>> booksInfo;
    List<String> temp;
    private void setData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        booksInfo = new ArrayList<>();

        for (DataSnapshot alert: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            n = n + 1;
            while(alert.child("pic"+n).exists());
            temp = new ArrayList<>();
            Log.d("image_name", (String) alert.child("image_name").getValue());
            Log.d("id", (String) alert.child("id").getValue());
            Log.d("image_path", (String) alert.child("image_path").getValue());
            temp.add((String) alert.child("image_name").getValue());
            temp.add((String) alert.child("id").getValue());
            temp.add((String) alert.child("image_path").getValue());
            booksInfo.add(temp);
        }

        if(booksInfo.size() > 0){
            setGridView();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data Found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

If I remove this line of code:

```
while(alert.child("pic"+n).exists());
```

The data inside Album1, 2, etc., will show up, but what I wanna do is show the data inside the pics. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If i get it right you get the image_name outside "Pic" element right? So it means that the alert object is not the "PicX" but the ALbumX. Why dont you do getChile("picX") and then alert.Child... What i mean is that your code is fine but you pulling childnodes 1lvl higher than what you need. One way to test it it to  rename the outside elements (not these under "pic" node)  "out_image_name" etc, you should get  get an error.

Comment: @gvlachakis yes i get the image_name outside "pic" i know i am pulling childnodes 1 lvl higher when i try to get nodes i want i dont get any data. i tried to change this line to booksInstance = firebaseDatabaseInstance.getReference("Album"+n);   but i am still not getting any data

Comment: Since you have set the reference to mainAlbum you get all the data nested to it. You call the setData on dataChange, i guess you reset the n variable each time, right? Or is it called multiple times any cause you problems? If i were you i would write this part again.

Comment: yes i call the setData on dataChange. i tried to remove n and put 1 instead just to get the first picture on the database but it's still not showing the data. so i guess this is not the problem right?

Comment: follow this tutorial https://androidheight.blogspot.in/2017/04/firebase-reatime-database.html